# Benchmark on different String dictionaries shows that the normal one is faster, and I don't know why

Tags: c#, .net, performance, dictionary, benchmarking

I'm doing some benchmark on several string dictionaries, because I wanted to find out how performs the different configurations, and I got surprised that the normal `Dictionary<String,String>` is the faster. Probably because I'm missing some concept or I'm doing something wrong, but these are the results I got:

```
Collection:             2147482 items.
Random Keys:            1000 keys.

Normal dictionary
        Add 1000 items:         573ms.
        Get 1000 keys:          0ms.

Normal Dictionary with OrdinalIgnoreCase comparer
        Add 1000 items:         642ms.
        Get 1000 keys:          0ms.

Normal Dictionary with InvariantCultureIgnoreCase comparer
        Add 1000 items:         1661ms.
        Get 1000 keys:          0ms.

Sorted dictionary
        Add 1000 items:         11996ms.
        Get 1000 keys:          5ms.

Sorted dictionary with OrdinalIgnoreCase comparer
        Add 1000 items:         11097ms.
        Get 1000 keys:          5ms.

Sorted dictionary with InvariantCultureIgnoreCase comparer
        Add 1000 items:         9814ms.
        Get 1000 keys:          5ms.
```

An this is the code I'm using to test it:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String[] col = GenerateCollectionUnsorted(Int32.MaxValue / 1000).ToArray();
        Int32 len = col.Length;
        Console.WriteLine("Collection:\t\t" + len.ToString() + " items.");

        String[] randomKeys = GetRandomKeys(col, 1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Random Keys:\t\t" + randomKeys.Length.ToString() + " keys.");

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Normal dictionary");
        TestDic(col, randomKeys, new Dictionary<String, String>());
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Normal Dictionary with OrdinalIgnoreCase comparer");
        TestDic(col, randomKeys, new Dictionary<String, String>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Normal Dictionary with InvariantCultureIgnoreCase comparer");
        TestDic(col, randomKeys, new Dictionary<String, String>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Sorted dictionary");
        TestDic(col,randomKeys, new SortedDictionary<String,String>());
        GC.Collect(); 
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Sorted dictionary with OrdinalIgnoreCase comparer");
        TestDic(col, randomKeys, new SortedDictionary<String, String>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Sorted dictionary with InvariantCultureIgnoreCase comparer");
        TestDic(col, randomKeys, new SortedDictionary<String, String>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        Console.WriteLine("\nEnd");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    static void TestDic(String[] col, String[] randomKeys, IDictionary<String,String> dic)
    {
        Stopwatch crono = new Stopwatch();
        
        crono.Start();
        foreach (String s in col)
            dic.Add(s, s);
        crono.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("\tAdd "+randomKeys.Length.ToString()+" items:\t\t" + crono.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + "ms.");

        crono.Reset();
        crono.Start();
        String sv;
        foreach (var rk in randomKeys)
        {
            sv = dic[rk];
            sv.ToString();
        }
        crono.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("\tGet " + randomKeys.Length.ToString() + " keys:\t\t" + crono.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + "ms.");
    }

    static String[] GetRandomKeys(String[] col, Int32 count)
    {
        Random ran = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

        List<Int32> indexSelection = new List<int>();
        List<String> selection = new List<string>();
        
        Int32 len = col.Length;
        
        while (indexSelection.Count < count)
        {
            Int32 value = ran.Next(0, len - 1);
            if (!indexSelection.Contains(value))
            {
                indexSelection.Add(value);
                selection.Add(col[value]);
            }
        }
        return selection.ToArray();
    }

    static IEnumerable<String> GenerateCollection(Int32 count)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            yield return i.ToString("X").PadLeft(5, '0');
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<String> GenerateCollectionUnsorted(Int32 amount)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < amount / 2; i++)
        {
            yield return i.ToString("X").PadLeft(5, '0');
            yield return (amount-i).ToString("X").PadLeft(5, '0');
        }
    }
```

Any idea why is this happening?

EDIT 1: It was my understanding that sorted dictionary would be slower adding items, and faster getting them because the collection is sorted. And also that comparing strings with a OrdinalIgnoreCase or InvariantCultureIgnoreCase should be faster that a normal comparision, so the seek should be faster. But maybe my understanding is completely wrong :D

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 2: As curiosity, I've made some test on String comparisons:

```
Collection:             2147482 items.
Random Keys:            1000 keys.

CurrentCulture
        LookUp:         158209ms.

CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
        LookUp:         160710ms.

InvariantCulture
        LookUp:         132765ms.

InvariantCultureIgnoreCase
        LookUp:         133409ms.

Ordinal
        LookUp:         36115ms.

OrdinalIgnoreCase
        LookUp:         36329ms.
```

Comment: You are using a SortedDict for test 2 and 3, not a normal dict as you write.

Comment: Right, I've corrected the code and the results. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because only the normal dictionary with the default comparer is actually a normal dictionary, all the others are sorted dictionaries.

So, the result is very consistent.

#### Edit:

With that fixed, the result is different. :)

A sorted dictionary is slower when adding items as they need to be sorted, but it's not faster when getting items. Searching the binary tree is fast, but searching the hash list that a regular dictionary uses is faster. When the binary tree grows, there will be more steps to locate each item, while a dictionary mostly grows by adding more buckets so the number of compares is barely affected.

Comparing strings with `Ordinal` is faster than regular (`CurrentCulture`) compare, and `OrdinalIgnoreCase` is faster than `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`, but it's not certain that `OrdinalIgnoreCase` is faster than `CurrentCulture`. `InvariantCulture` compare is not faster than a regular compare, it just uses a different culture. The reason that ordinal compare is a lot faster is that it doesn't have to bother with cultural settings at all.

By the way, I noticed an error in the GetRandomKeys method. It will never pick the last item, as you are getting a random number between 0 and Length - 2.

Comment: It was my understanding that sorted dictionary would be slower adding items, and faster getting them because the collection is sorted. And also that comparing strings with a OrdinalIgnoreCase or InvariantCultureIgnoreCase should be faster that a normal comparision, so the seek should be faster. But maybe my understanding is completely wrong :D

Comment: @bitbitbit: Not completely wrong, but the comparisons doesn't give a clear indication. If you for example compared `OrdinalIgnorareCase` to `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`, you would get a more predictable result.

Comment: Thanks. See in the main post, I've updated it with a test with String comparisons. Now I have a better idea about it, and I've sort out some missconceptions I had. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

From the [MSDN documentation on `SortedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx):

> The `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` generic class is a binary search tree with O(log n) retrieval, where n is the number of elements in the dictionary.

From the [docs on `Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

> Retrieving a value by using its key is very fast, close to O(1), because the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class is implemented as a hash table.

Therefore it should not be surprising that `Dictionary` can outperform `SortedDictionary` in many cases.

Comment: You had the words I was looking for.  +1 for probably the best explanation as to "why"

Comment: Thank you, great response. Sorry for choosing the @Guffa response as answer. Yours is pretty good too.

Comment: @bitbitbit: No apology needed, but thanks for the comment.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm failing to see why you would be surprised at the results.

"normal"/unsorted would obviously be faster than a sorted dictionary as the sorted one would have to perform extra operations.

The two "normal" ones that have extra options both require extra processing as well.

Comment: It was my understanding that sorted dictionary would be slower adding items, and faster getting them because the collection is sorted. And also that comparing strings with a OrdinalIgnoreCase or InvariantCultureIgnoreCase should be faster that a normal comparision, so the seek should be faster. But maybe my understanding is completely wrong :D

Comment: @bitbitbit: Why would ignoring case make comparing strings faster?  The simplest algorithm for comparing strings simply compares the ordinal values at each position; ignoring case requires a separate operation on both values before comparing.  It's easy to see that a case-insensitive compare will always take longer.

Comment: @bitbitbit: ditto what Daniel said.  Also read his main response.  Internally the different types are implemented very differently.

Comment: @bitbitbit: And while extracting values from a sorted collection is faster than extracting them from an unsorted list (O(log n) instead of O(n)), extracting them from an (arbitrarily ordered) [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) is even faster: amortized O(1).